# Why does the icing and donut get stuck to each other although they are different objects?

Tags: mesh

I'm new at Blender and was incredibly happy to finish a beautiful donut animation this morning.

However, after that I planned to make a new one to repeat what I learned, and I have been stuck 6h adding the icing... Each time I've made some shape to the donut (with the proportional editing and the shrink fatten tool) and duplicate part of the donut to make the icing (https://youtu.be/7wKnPclzYY8?list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&t=157) both layers get stuck in each other. If I don't give it any shape before (so only duplicate the upper part of the donut without making any bumps on it before) it works fine and the donut and the icing stay as separate pieces.

I uploaded my file here in case someone would be able to help me... https://we.tl/t-1xzTo17hNW.  Really don't understand, when I made the first donut I managed, but now I've tried at least 15 times so guess it's some setting I've messed up?

Comment: Your 2 objects move together because you haven't disabled the Poportional Editing, is it what you're talking about?

Comment: I agree with moonboots - it's less likely you "messed up some setting", and more likely you simply forgot to turn proportional editing _off_ after using it to make the "bumps". Remember - it works (will still be on) in Object mode too. Don't worry - it's messed with all our heads at some point - especially in those times when the (blue) influence circle becomes larger than the viewport.